# I need help to build notification functionality

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I need help to build notification functionality , below criteria:

Backend is **WordPress**

1. Call an REST API build UI and store it in cache or somewhere.
2. If there is new data in API(backend), then automatically call API and build UI with new content and show notification for new content.

Currently using **flutter_local_notifications** package and able to show notification on button click.

What I want to build is.

Even if the app is open/close/terminated, if there is new data posted in backend, the Rest API should automatically trigger on it own fetch new data, build UI and show the notification.

Note: Tried to use **onesignal_flutter**

Open for all suggestions and help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase cloud messaging for Push Notifications.
here is the guide to setup FCM : https://medium.com/inspireui/setup-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-push-notification-for-flutter-apps-8c767fe64e54

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the lead, I have tried using Firebase cloud messaging for Push Notifications, but the backend I am using is **WordPress** and the **API** that I am using is 3rd party which is integrated in **WordPress**.

Comment: Basically FCM Provide support to generate notifications through the API . Here is the guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref from here you can check how to call API with passing the data using FCM